# Add Object to existing Xelement

Tags: c#, xml, xml-serialization

I have a object obj with 2 properties p1, p2. and a XElement like:

```
<root><AA><BB>BB</BB></AA></root>
```

I'd like to make my Xelement as:

```
<root><AA><BB>BB</BB><CC><p1>val1</p1><p2>val2</p2></CC></AA></root>
```

I make a new XElement from obj

```
XElement x = new XElement("CC",new XElement("p1", obj.p1),new XElement("p2", obj.p2));
```

and insert it in AA element. is ther a better way by serializing my obj and convert it to XElement? (Because My object can change in the future) . Thanks for any help.
Here is my attempt to use XmlSerializer:

```
   XElement xelem = reqRet.RequestDefinition;
    xelem.Descendants("AA").ToList().ForEach(reqitem =>
    {
        using (MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream())
        {
            using (TextWriter tw = new StreamWriter(ms))
            {
                XmlSerializer ser = new XmlSerializer(typeof(obj));
                ser.Serialize(tw, ObjVAL);
                schElem = new XElement( XElement.Parse(Encoding.ASCII.GetString(ms.ToArray())));
                reqitem.Add(schElem);
            }
        }
        reqitem.Add(schElem);
    });
```

Comment: What are the properties p1 and p2?  What do you envision them changing to in the future?  Either way you'd have to change your code somewhere, it's just going to be a matter of where (serialization attributes on the class or code for generating your XEleent)

Comment: Dan, the obj has all kind of properties like string, date, bool etc. I'm looking for a generic way to serialize the obj. I tried by making MemoryStream, textWriter, then serialize obj to TextWriter, the problem is coming with xml header

Comment: Have you tried `XmlSerializer`? https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.serialization.xmlserializer%28v=vs.110%29.aspx

Comment: Yes I tried XML Serializer, but I'm getting :
<MyOBj xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
How can I change it to <CC> as the root of this XElement?

Comment: Post your XmlSerializer attempt.  You need to use attributes etc. as inthe documentation

Comment: I added to the code. Thank you Dan

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/74951/discussion-between-dan-field-and-frenchi-in-la).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you're open to using `XmlSerializer`, use the `XmlRoot` attribute; try adding the following to your class declaration:

```
[XmlRoot(Namespace = "www.contoso.com", 
   ElementName = "CC", 
   DataType = "string", 
   IsNullable=true)]
public class MyObj
{
    ...
```

See https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.serialization.xmlrootattribute%28v=vs.110%29.aspx for more information.

After that, you can use this code:

```
    XElement xelem = XElement.Parse("<root><AA><BB>BB</BB></AA></root>");
    MyObj myObj = new MyObj();

    XmlSerializer ser = new XmlSerializer(typeof(MyObj));
    foreach (XElement reqitem in xelem.Descendants("AA"))
    {
        using (MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream())
        {
            ser.Serialize(ms, myObj);                
            reqitem.Add(XElement.Parse(Encoding.UTF8.GetString(ms.ToArray())));


        }
    }
```

This gives the desired output.

If you want to remove the XMLNS declarations, you can use `.Attributes.Remove()` after creating the XElement.

Comment: Now I have the following as root:
<myOBJ xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns="www.contoso.com">

Comment: Thanks Dan, with your help  i found a way to remove xmlns attribute from my Xelement, By adding myXelem.Attributes().Remove(). Please add it to your answer, and I will accept it as the right answer.